# redis-cli not working if port is changed

Tags: redis, port, redis-cli

I am using `redis 2.4` . When I change the port in "redis.conf" file to another port `redis-cli` stops working. It shows

> Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Unknown error not
>   connected>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `redis.conf` file dictates the server's behavior. To tell the command line interface to connect to your newly-defined-non-default port, use the `-p` switch, e.g.:

```
$ redis-cli -p 12758
```

Comment: thanks for replay . but i am using windows when i  run "redis-cli -p 12758" in cmd it showing "Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:12758: Unknown error
not connected>"

Comment: Replace `12758`  with the port you configured (in redis.conf)

Comment: Thanks its working . But is there any way to run  Redis Client .